# What does the CustomNSError protocol do and why should I adopt it?

Tags: swift

What does the `CustomNSError` protocol do and why should I adopt it?
The documentation provided by Apple only states:

> Describes an error type that specifically provides a domain, code, and
>   user-info dictionary.

I already searched on google, but couldn't find anything related to my questions there.

Comment: In Objective-C, we use `NSError`, and we can use them for customization. Apparently, in Swift, you can't use the equivalent `Error` which is only for Apple, and have to use `CustomNSError`.

Comment: I can create Errors such as ´enum NetworkingError: Error{}´ and it works pretty well. I'm just curious what to do with that protocol?

Answer (score 6):

> Every type that conforms to the `Error` protocol is **implicitly** bridged
>   to `NSError`. This has been the case since Swift 2, **where the compiler**
>   **provides a domain (i.e., the mangled name of the type) and code (based**
>   **on the discriminator of the enumeration type).**

So you need `CustomNSError`, `LocalizedError` and `RecoverableError` for explicit runtime mapping to NSError.

More info [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md).

**Example:**

```
// Errors

enum ServiceError: Int, Error, CustomNSError {
    case unknownError = -1000
    case serverReturnBadData

    //MARK: - CustomNSError

    static var errorDomain: String = "reverse.domain.service.error"

    var errorCode: Int { return self.rawValue }
    var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] { return [:]  } //TODO: Return something meaningful here
}

extension NSError {

    var serviceError: ServiceError? {
        return (self.domain == ServiceError.errorDomain
            ? ServiceError(rawValue: self.code)
            : nil)
    }

    convenience init(serviceError: ServiceError) {
        self.init(
            domain: ServiceError.errorDomain,
            code: serviceError.rawValue,
            userInfo: serviceError.errorUserInfo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case somethingFatal(Int)
    case somethingNonFatal(Int)
}
```

If you log swift errors with associative property to firebase crashlytics, in this example 
`CustomError.somethingFatal` will be logged as CustomError code: 0

`CustomError.somethingNonFatal` will be logged as CustomError code: 1

If you conform to `CustomNSError`

```
extension CustomError: CustomNSError {
    static var errorDomain: String = "custom.error.domain"
    var errorCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case let .somethingFatal(someCode):
            //specify what you want to return
        case let .somethingNonFatal(someCode):
            //specify what you want to return
        }
    }

    var userInfo: [String : Any] {
        switch self {
        case let .somethingFatal(someCode):
            //specify what you want to return
        case let .somethingNonFatal(someCode):
            //specify what you want to return
        }
    }

}
```

You can specify the correct code or userInfo based on the property