# Evaluating if Error is NSError always succeeds while casting Error as NSError gives a compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, nserror

We had an issue with an Error object that crashes in Crashlytics' Objective-c code because it doesn't respond to `userInfo` (a member of `NSError`), while investigating I stumbled upon this weird behavior in Swift.

In a playground, I tried creating a class `SwiftError` implementing the `Error` protocol:

```
class SwiftError: Error {
}

let sError = SwiftError()

if sError is NSError { // Generates a warning: 'is' test is always true
    print("Success")
} else {
    print("Fail")
}
// Prints Fail

let nsError = sError as NSError
//Compiler Error: 'SwiftError' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

- Checking if the SwiftError is NSError gives a warning that it always succeeds but fails runtime.
- Casting SwiftError as an NSError gives a compiler error.

Can someone help explain to me why this happens and how could I know if a class implementing the `Error` protocol actually *is* an `NSError` or not ?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont post screen shots post your code

Comment: you can conditionally cast your error object `as? NSError`

Comment: Btw why would you need to cast the `Error` to `NSError`? If you show your actual issue we can provide a better alternative

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189606/what-does-the-customnserror-protocol-do-and-why-should-i-adopt-it — I probably should not have answered.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. The cast `sError  as NSError` fails only if `sError` is an instance of a class, it compiles with a struct or enum instead. And even with a class, `let nsError = sError as Error as NSError` compiles.

Comment: I wasn’t actually trying to cast an `Error as NSError` quite the opposite really, I was trying to figure out if an `Error` was indeed an `NSError`, when it showed me that warning that it always succeeds. That got me to dig more into that bridging behaviour in a playground. What I saw didn’t make sense to me so I posted this question. @matt @leo

Answer (score 3):

There is something odd about the nature of the bridging between NSError and Error. They are bridged *for communication purposes* — that is, they can travel back and forth between Swift and Cocoa; and an error that comes from Cocoa *is* an NSError (and NSError adopts the Error protocol in Swift, to allow for this); but your `class` that you declare as conforming to Error is itself *not* an NSError.

> because it doesn't respond to `userInfo`

If you need your Swift Error type to carry `userInfo` information for Cocoa's benefit, then you were looking for the CustomNSError protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/customnserror

Comment: Interestingly, `let nsError = sError as NSError` does compile if `sError` is an instance of `struct SwiftError: Error` or `enum SwiftError: Error` – it only fails to compile with `class SwiftError: Error`

Comment: @MartinR I presume that it's like Hashable: Swift can inject conformity into an enum or struct but not a class. I did in fact consider commenting on that too in my answer...

Comment: But `let nsError = sError as Error as NSError` does compile and work. It looks like a bug to me, but I may be completely wrong. So I decided to ask the experts: https://forums.swift.org/t/bridging-to-nserror-fails-for-instances-of-a-class/45451

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug to me, I have filed it as [SR-14322](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-14322).

According to [SE-0112 Improved NSError Bridging](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md),

> Every type that conforms to the Error protocol is implicitly bridged to NSError.

This works with struct and enum types, but apparently *not* with class types.

You can replace your `class SwiftError: Error` by a `struct SwiftError: Error` to solve the problem. If that is not possible for some reason then the following “trick” worked in my test:

```
let nsError = sError as Error as NSError
```

That compiles *and* gives the expected results:

```
class SwiftError: Error {}

extension SwiftError: CustomNSError {
    public static var errorDomain: String { "MyDomain" }
    public var errorCode: Int { 13 }
    public var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] { ["Foo" : "Bar" ] }
}

let sError = SwiftError()

let nsError = sError as Error as NSError
print(nsError.userInfo)
// Output: ["Foo": "Bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the fact that Error protocol conforms to Sendable protocol, while a class type (not struct) has some special requirements to conform to Sendable, such as it must be a final class, etc...